# How do I make multiple copies of a set of polygons in a Vertex Buffer Array?

Tags: vb.net, opengl, vbo, opentk

In OpengL 1, in Visual Basic with OpenTK, if I want a hundred cubes all arranged in circle i'd write

```
glRef = GL.GenLists(1)
GL.NewList(glRef, ListMode.Compile)
GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Traingles)

GL.Vertex3....for the vertices of a cube

GL.End()
GL.EndList()
```

which would give me glRef as a handle with which I could do

```
For i = 0 to 100
    GL.PushMatrix()
    GL.Rotate(3.6*i, 0, 0, 1)
    GL.Translate(5.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    GL.CallList(glRef)
    GL.PopMatrix()
Next
```

and get a hundred cubes all arranged in a circle.

How do I do the same sort of thing in Open GL 2.0 or higher with Vertex Buffer Objects?

I start off with

```
GL.GenBuffer(VBOid) 
Dim VertexArray() As Single = {....for the vertices of a cube }
```

then do some binding of it to a vertex buffer

```
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VBOid(0))
GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, SizeOf(GetType(Single)) * VertexArray.Count, VertexArray, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw)
GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, False, 0, VertexArray)
```

and then in my draw routine I do something along the lines of

```
GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray)
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, PrimitiveID(0))
GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles)
```

but at this point adding a second DrawBuffer command together with transforms doesn't seem to create me a second cube. I've been bashing my head against a wall, looking all over the internet and I can't find a straight forward reference which tells me how to do it, or even confirmation that it's possible.

Is this not the way its supposed to work, am I just supposed to send a hundred sets of cube vertices, or is there a way to copy a vertex buffer object and apply transforms to it? (Or is I'm probably doing it wrong somewhere and I need to go on a bug hunt - any tips for that would be helpful)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `GL.DrawBuffer` is the correct command in this place. It is used to specify in the context of FBOs which attachment points can be written.

Since you try to draw a VBO here, I would expect the use of `GL.DrawArrays` or `GL.DrawElements`.

Comment: Yeah sorry it should have been either of those, its DrawElements in my code, but I've massively simplified it here for explanation purposes. I've edited it to reflect that.

So given that, any idea how to clone objects in VBOs?